# Aligning images of different height but same width into a whole div with css

Tags: html, image, css

Good day all,
I am creating a div filled with images of same width but different height such as cutedogpix.com. But it seems they are not aligning properly and align properly if only the width and height are the same. Any Idedas. Please it would

Comment: Please post the code you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve that in many ways, the simplest of them is a masonry plugin [masonry pluging page](http://masonry.desandro.com/). On that page you can find documentation, examples everything. Have fun.

Comment: THat was an awosme pluging. Thanks alot it works like a charm. :). Thanks

Comment: @user1868773 You're welcome :) You should then mark this answer as accepted (click the green checkmark next to it), to also mark your question as solved

Answer (score 0):

### Make blocks float

You can split your images content in columns, and make them float left. If you have few colums you will get a very similar effect like on the page you gave there.

### Example

Here you can find something I have prepared for you:`(http://jsfiddle.net/AuvGv/1/)`

Comment: Thanks alot. Problem with that is I am loading images src from database it will be very difficult to devide them int columns. Thanks a million